# php variables in html swf wrapper?

Tags: php, html, actionscript-3

Can you place php varibles in the html wrapper for a swf, that could be read into the swf when it loads?

Perhaps using a param?

```
 $myVariable = "$var1,$var2,$var3";
```

like this with php in the html?

```
<param name=FlashVars value="$myVariable" />
```

or perhaps ?

```
<param name=FlashVars value="myVariable=$myVariable" />
```

Then perhaps in the swf with as3 using something like this?

```
var myloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
myloader.load(new URLRequest(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters))
myloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded)

function onLoaded(evt:Event)
{
trace(myloader.data)

}
```

Unsure how to access it using the correct path to the param and then how to get the php variable $myVariable into myloader.data?

Greater wisdom required than mine.
Kindest regards.
Adrian.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
<php 
    $myVariable = 'myvar=myValue&myothervar=myOtherValue';
?>
<param name=FlashVars value="<?php echo $myVariable; ?>" />
```

or...

```
<php 
    $myVariable = 'myValue';
    $myOtherVariable = 'myOtherValue';
?>
<param name=FlashVars value="myvar=<?php echo $myVariable; ?>&myothervar=<?php echo $myOtherVariable; ?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you very helpful. Still unsure about swf as3 path to the wrapper. Tried this.root.loaderInfo.parameters but this and root caused problem.

Comment: have you tried using `var params:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;`?

Comment: Hi Aaron thankyou tried that, will it give errors if I am testing the swf on its own? DeBug is hard since it is refering to a wrapper that isnt there until its live so to speak.

Comment: You'll want to wrap your instantiation of the loaderInfo object in a `try...catch` statement that defines default values if `loaderInfo` can't access the parameters of the containing `embed` object.

Comment: Ok going to edit my original post so I can show you where I got to.

Answer (score 0):

..and remember... the variables being passed in should be name-value pairs separated with ampersands...

```
 $myVariable = "varone=somevalue&vartwo=someothervalue";
```

Comment: Thank you helped me alot. Still have problem with the swf path to the wrapper.